# What is the correct way/can you chain two AngularJs service calls and then perform a function with the returned data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to chain these two service calls, and with the results perform a `forEach loop` to filter my data, but get a **TypeError: "SocialMediaUserService.channelProfiles is not a function"** message in Chrome.

**However,** this works in IE, and no warning or message. :)

```
function getChannelProfiles() {

    GetUserAccessService.returnBrandProfileID().then(function (brandProfileID) {

        SocialMediaUserService.channelProfiles().then(function (channelProfiles) {

            channelProfiles.forEach(function (channel) {

                if (channel.brand_profile_id === brandProfileID && channel.channel_type === 'facebook') {
                    $scope.facebookChannels.push(channel.channel_url);
                    console.log($scope.facebookChannels);
                }

            });
        });
    });
}
```

**EDIT:** This is my `SocialMediaUserService.channelProfiles` service call:

```
this.channelProfiles = function () {

  var channelProfiles = pullSocialMediaData('list_channel_profiles.json');

  console.log("Channel Profiles Logged: " + channelProfiles);

  return channelProfiles;

}
```

This is my `SocialMediaUserService.returnBrandProfileID` service call:

```
this.returnBrandProfileID = function () {

  var brandProfileID = $q.defer();

  if (angular.isUndefined($sessionStorage.brandProfileID)) {

      GetDataService.getItems('GetUserAccess/' + $cookies.get('authenticationID'))

      .success(function (accessObject) {

          brandProfileID.resolve(accessObject.FusewareID);
      })

      .error(function (error, status) {
          console.error('Fuseware API error: ' + error + ' Status message: ' + status);
      });
  }

  else {
      brandProfileID.resolve($sessionStorage.brandProfileID);
  }

  return brandProfileID.promise;

};
```

**Edit 2:** This is the pullSocialMediaData function:

```
function pullSocialMediaData(url) {

  var userData = $q.defer();

  GetFusionDataService.getItems(url)
    .success(function (data) {
        userData.resolve(data);
    })
    .error(function (error, status) {

    });

  return userData.promise;

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Could you post here your SocialMediaUserService service?

Comment: The problem could be in the SocialMediaUserService, so in order to help you, you should include the complete service js file and maybe the complete controller js file.

Comment: Is the problem not perhaps the calling of `SocialMediaUserService.channelProfiles()` after this `GetUserAccessService.returnBrandProfileID().then(function (brandProfileID) {`?

Comment: I have added the `pullSocialMediaData` function to the equation. Apart from what I have posted, there isn't much else that should have an impact. The `controller` and `services` works perfectly with the rest of the functionality, it is only this one method I created where I chain 2 service calls and then have the `loop` function that seems to have an issue.

Comment: To understand the type error, I think we need the context in which `SocialMediaUserService.channelProfiles` is defined, to be sure `this` is correctly bound.

Comment: @NewbieJavaDeveloper I refreshed a couple time, and now it seems to work.

Comment: @trincot it works now. Refreshed a couple time after I made some changes, and it worked. Changed back the changes I made (i.e. back to original as per post) refreshed another 50 odd times, and it works. Not sure what the issue was. Thank you for your help!

Comment: But I think `SocialMediaUserService.channelProfiles()` is a promise but in the declaration there is no return of promise neither any resolve is there. Secondly, `pullSocialMediaData()` is used as a regular function whereas it should be used as a promise

Comment: @NewbieJavaDeveloper May I ask that you perhaps add an answer as per your suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SocialMediaUserService.channelProfiles` might be designed like this :

```
this.channelProfiles = function () {

  var channelProfilesPromise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject){

    pullSocialMediaData('list_channel_profiles.json').then(function(result){

        console.log("Channel Profiles Logged: " + result);
        resolve(result);
    });

  });

    return channelProfilesPromise

};
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. You mentioned "'pullSocialMediaData()' is used as a regular function whereas it should be used as a promise", but it seems correct... Here is a link to the use of `q.defer()`: https://toddmotto.com/promises-angular-q#qdefer Do you agree, or am I missing the plot?

Comment: I am saying that `var channelProfiles = pullSocialMediaData('list_channel_profiles.json');` is a use of simple function returning any value. It shold be `pullSocialMediaData('list_channel_profiles.json').then(callback_function(result)).catch(callback_function());`

Comment: Ahhh! I thought you referred to the actual method, not the call. :) I get it, thank you.